# Android - Create second instance of my app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have created my first app using Eclipse and now wish to implement NFC into it. However I don't want to add it yet to my first app in case I encounter problems. I wish to copy and paste my app into Eclipse a second time so I can have 2 versions in my workspace (App1 & App1NFC).

Is copying and pasting and then renaming the NFC version a safe way to do this. I'm worried the Java source files may conflict each other. Will renaming the project name sufficient enough or will I have to change other things in the manifest/res folders etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look into using a version control system such as git. You could create a branch with the NFC code and then be able to switch back and forth pretty easily.

Comment: or VisualSVN for a free private local SVN cache. Good answer +1.  In respect to the renaming, the name spaces will clash still. You would need to change it in the manifest. Else the app will install over the other.

Answer (score 1):

If you want two apps to run on the same device then the *package names* should not be *identical* to each other so that they won't conflict with each other.or else installation of the existing app will be replaced by installing app.

i.e

If app1 has the package name as com.mycompanyname.myappname 
then make sure the other app doesn't have the same package you could rename it into something like com.mycompanyname.myappname1

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy the entire folder and rename it to whatever you like.Then you can open it as another project

Btw

Why don't you use Android Studio?

Comment: Use Eclipse for App1 and then use AS for App1NFC?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems when copying projects(folders) but I don't know if you can open eclipse project in Android Studio(not sure because of Gradle)